# App Using WebBrowser.DocumentText And DomDocument.DesignMode Works In IE8 And Does Not Work In IE9

Tags: browser, domdocument, designmode

Yes my use of webBrowser control work fine in IE8 and not in IE9.  It seems that setting the HTMLDocument from DesignMode = "On" to DesignMode = "Off" removes the document from the WebBrowser. I made this example that shows my problem. There are two buttons and one webBrowser on a form. One button does the webBrowser.DocumentText and the other button toggles between document.DesignMode = "On" and "Off". The DesignMode button uses "CheckOnClick". I hope that you can see what it does.

Now if we run this on a machine with IE8; then toggling in and out of DesignMode does leave the webBrowser.Document in place.  Now if we run this on a machine with IE9; then setting DesignMode to "On" or to "Off" causes the webBrowser document to change to ".  If the webBrowser is in DesignMode = "On", and we set the DocumentText; then the webBrowser is now in DesignMode = "Off".

I have been unable to find a way to work around this behavior to be able to use webBrowser.DocumentText and DesignMode at the same time in IE9.  The IE8 behavior works for me and the IE9 does not.  I am unable to imagine how I might be able to set the DocumentText and then be able to edit it.

Is there a setting or work around to get the IE8 behavior back?  It seems imposible to be able to use DocumentText and DesignMode on the same document in IE9.

Thanks in advance for any help.  I have taken a lot of time to search no my own to find an answer, and have been unable so far.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<HTML><BODY>Initial text</BODY></HTML>";
    }

    private void designModeToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.designModeToolStripButton.Checked)
            webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.GetType().GetProperty("designMode").SetValue(webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument, "On", null);
        else
            webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.GetType().GetProperty("designMode").SetValue(webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument, "Off", null);
    }

    private void setTextToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<HTML><BODY>New text</BODY></HTML>";
    }
}
```

I also tried doing the setting of DesignMode in the WebBrowserDocumentCompleted event, and the same problem happens (automatically).

```
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.designModeToolStripButton.Checked)
            webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.GetType().GetProperty("designMode").SetValue(webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument, "On", null);
        else
            webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.GetType().GetProperty("designMode").SetValue(webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument, "Off", null);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you set DocumentText, it resets designMode to "Inherit" and when you set designMode to "On", it clears DocumentText.  This seems to only happen on IE 9.

This fix worked for me:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Body.SetAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
```

Comment: If I could give 100 Up's, you would get it - I looked up the whole internet for a solution on this and this is the first (and only one?) that worked! Kudos, man!

Comment: I agree Acme, this is the ONLY one that works.... I have been pulling my hair out for days now fighting this.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Eibrahim.. it seems to work for me as well in my vb.net project. I used it like

I put this code in DocumentCompleted event and it worked well Win7+IE8 and Win7+IE9

```
    Try
        If WebBrowser1.Document IsNot Nothing AndAlso WebBrowser1.Document.Body IsNot Nothing Then
            WebBrowser1.Document.Body.SetAttribute("contentEditable", "true")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        DumpError(ex)
    End Try
```

Comment: The way to thank someone on this site is to accept his/her answer. You can do so by clicking on the check left to the answer.

Comment: Thank you Ranjan! your helped also.